# Problem access relationship data in view - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a site which has members with a has_one relationship to their profile.

I want to display some of their member profile information in the admin dashboard I've created.

In the rails console I can access the information using:

```
member = Member.find(1)
member.profile.first_name
```

In my controller

```
def index
    @members = Member.all
end
```

In my admin view I have

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
    <p><%= member.id %></p>
    <p><%= member.profile.first_name %></p>
<% end %>
```

except this raise an undefined method error

```
undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I access the profile information in my view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think some of your members do not have a profile associated with it. To prevent the error, you can do something like this:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
    <p><%= member.id %></p>
    <p><%= member.profile ? member.profile.first_name : "-" %></p>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

You are better off including `profile` in the controller itself, in order to prevent [N + 1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) query problem. You can do this in the controller:

```
def index
  @members = Member.includes(:profile)
end
```